# What would be the time complexity of this when i is doubled in each iteration?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
int i = 1;
while(i < N) {
  i *= 2;
}
```

Since we are visiting 1,2,4,8,16...(Squares). I think the big-O time complexity should be O(log n). Is the answer right? Is the way I arrived at the solution correct?

Comment: Yes, the reasoning is correct. However, you should avoid saying `int` because then you get into overflow territory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. Generally speaking, if a value grows exponentially, it can only do so logarithmically many times before exceeding some fixed value.